# define a global site template (html site) for site with jQuery / RoR

Tags: jquery, html, templates

We are building a new website with RoR on the backend (server side) and jQuery on the client side (*.htm files).

Right now, every new page that i create i need to copy all the "common areas" to any other page (like header, footer, menu, etc.).

Fairly retoric question: is there any way to "templetize it" so one page inherit the template from another.

I know that ASP.NET is using master-pages for this, but as you can see, this is not our case.

Please help :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, these are called layouts. To find the current layout, Rails first looks for a file in app/views/layouts with the same base name as the controller. If there is no such controller-specific layout, Rails will use app/views/layouts/application.html.erb or app/views/layouts/application.builder. Within the layout, you have access to methods for combining different bits of content, such as yield and content_for.Read this before starting your project:

```
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html
```

Comment: but taking the RoR out of the picture for a moment (because our plan is simply use it as a web-service for phase 1), is there any way to do it purely in html/jQuery?

Comment: it's the server side language that allows you to create the "inheritance structure" you speak of. You can use javascript to send a GET request to the server, which renders json or text back, whereby you can then include into the document, but nevertheless the right way to do it is server-side.

Comment: Maybe this would interest you: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Oct/13/Client-Templating-with-jQuery